# Undefined variable: query & mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

Tags: php

I'm busy with a To Do list in php but I'm stuck now with the error codes Notice: Undefined variable: query in C:\xampp\htdocs\To-do\Includes\add-task.php on line 14

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\To-do\Includes\add-task.php on line 14

Here are my codes:

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple to-Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="task-list">
      <ul>
        <?php
        require ("includes/connect.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows>0){
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query) ) {

  $task_id = $row('id');
  $task_name = $row ('task');

  echo '<li>
                     <span>'.$task_name.'</span>
         <img id="'.$task_id.'" class="delete-button" width="10px" src="images/close.svg" />
      </li>';

}
 }


        ?>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <form class ="add-new-task" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="new-task" placeholder="Add a new item..." />
  </form>
</div>
</body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
add_task();
delete_task();

function add_task() {
$('.add-new-task').submit (function() {
var new_task = $('.add-new-task input [name=new-task]') .val();

if (new_task != '') {
  $.post ('includes/add-task.php', {task: new_task}, function (data){
    $('.add-new-task input [name=new-task]').val('');
    $(data).appendTo('.task-list ul').hide().fadeIn();
  });
}
return false;
});

}

function delete_task() {
        $('.delete-button').click(function(){
      var current_element = $(this);
      var id = $(this).attr('id');

      $.post('includes/delete-task.php', { task_id: id }, function() {
    current_element.parent().fadeOut("fast", function() { $(this).remove(); });
     });
        });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

add-task.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['task']))
$task = strip_tags ($_POST['task'] );
$date = date ('Y-m-d');
$time = date ('H:i:s');

require ("connect.php");
if(!empty ($task))
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tasks VALUES ('','$task, '$date', '$time')");

if(!empty ($task))
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task='$task' and date='$date' and time='$time'");
  if(empty ($query))
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
  $task_id = $row ['id'];
  $task_name = $row['task'];

  echo '<li><span>'.$task_name.'</span><img id="'.$task_id.'" class="delete-button" width="10px" src="images/close.svg" /></li>';

}

mysql_close();





 ?>
```

and if I insert a table in phpmyadmin is this error:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\To-do\index.php on line 19

Comment: First of all, start using curly braces after `if`/`else` statements _every time_, no matter if they are followed by just one statement.

Answer (score 2):

Line 11 of add-task.php is checking if $query is empty.

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a resource on success, or FALSE if no results are found for 'SELECT' statements. So you should check if $query is not false, rather than if it is empty.

Additionally, you're getting 'Function name must be a string' because on line 19 you have '$task_id = $row('id');'

In PHP you access elements of arrays using square brackets, so I think you meant to do $task_id = $row['id']. You use brackets for passing arguments to functions, so the interpreter thinks you're trying to call a function

Answer (score 1):

So. What do these lines of code mean?

```
if(!empty ($task))
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task='$task' and date='$date' and time='$time'");
```

They mean that if variable `task` is not empty, variable `query` will get the value returned by the SQL statement. Please note that `query` was never initialized before in your code, so it will never be created if this test fails (i.e. `task` is empty) and it will be null if the SQL statement for some reason doesn't return the data you're looking for.

OK. Then. What do these lines of code mean?

```
if(empty ($query))
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
```

They mean that if `query` is empty (like... Null? Not existing?) the `while` statement will be executed. And what does it do? It uses `query`!

Summing up, you're doing this: if variable `query` doesn't exist, you use it.

Hence the two errors, because you can't pass a non-existing or null variable to `mysql_fetch_assoc` function.

**EDIT:** I didn't notice the last error.
Like user1614986 said, you are trying to access an array using round brackets, which are for passing data to functions. Array elements are accessed with square brackets!